# How can I select parent elements that contain empty element with XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<rootelement>
   <parentelement>
      <mytype>123</mytype>
      <myvalue>abc</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
   <parentelement>
      <mytype></mytype>
      <myvalue>xyz</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
   <parentelement>
      <mytype />
      <myvalue>qwe</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
   <parentelement>
      <myvalue>asdf</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
</rootelement>
```

I want to use XPath to select:

```
   <parentelement>
      <mytype></mytype>
      <myvalue>xyz</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
   <parentelement>
      <mytype />
      <myvalue>qwe</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
   <parentelement>
      <myvalue>asdf</myvalue>
   </parentelement>
```

When I try this in my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="/rootelement/parentelement/mytype[not(text())]/.."/>
```

it fails with:

> Unexpected token in pattern, found ".."

When I try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/rootelement/parentelement/mytype[not(text())]/parent::*"/>
```

it fails with:

> Axis in pattern must be child or attribute

How can I select parent elements that contain empty mytype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match on the element and put the condition into a predicate e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/rootelement/parentelement[mytype[not(node())]]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there simple way to extend it a little bit and also select those parents that have missing mytype (not present at all)?

Comment: You can use `or` expressions e.g. `<xsl:template match="/rootelement/parentelement[not(mytype) or mytype[not(node())]]"/>`

Comment: Sorry Martin, for my simultaneous answer, didn't see your post when I submitted. However, I will just leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

You say "parent elements that contain empty mytype". So you select `parentelement`, followed by a condition: it should contain `mytype`, and `mytype` should be empty. By "empty", I assume that you mean no text or elements, so `node()` is preferrable:

```
/rootelement/parentelement[mytype[not(node())]]
```